# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'validate'

Tags: jquery, validation

I keep getting this error message.

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#formEmployee").validate({
            rules: {
                EmployeeModel_Name: "required"
            },
            messages: {
                EmployeeModel_Name: "Please specify your name"

            }
        })

        $("#btnSave").click(function () {
            $("#formEmployee").valid();
        });

});
```

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Get, new { name = "formEmployee", id = "formEmployee" }))
    {
        <fieldset>
        <legend>EmployeeModel</legend>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmployeeModel.Name, new { @class = "required" })
        <p>
        <input id="btnSave" type="button" value="Save" />
        </p>
        </fieldset>
    }
```

Generated html

```
<form action="/Dealer/ManageEmployee" id="formEmployee" method="get" name="formEmployee">    <fieldset>
        <legend>EmployeeModel</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="EmployeeModel_Name">Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input class="text-box single-line" id="EmployeeModel_Name" name="EmployeeModel.Name" type="text" value="">

        </div>
        <p>
            <input id="btnSave" type="button" value="Save">
            <input id="btnBack" type="button" value="Back">
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: For client-side problems, please _always_ show _client-side_ code (and not whatever obscure script on your _server_ might be generating the HTML).

Comment: You have two `validate` .JS files. Is that intended?

Comment: first of all you don't need validat.js and validate.min.js. either use min.js or js only... and secondly about the error..make sure your path to the validate js file is correct

Comment: @bipen, i have tried with min.js and with js, one at a time and together and nether i get the same error. The path's are correct

Comment: @acdcjunior Does not work with ether validate file

Comment: could you post the html that gets generated by your server-side code?

Comment: You are using two versions of jQuery. <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> Try using only one!!

Answer (score 0):

Inspect your page load with Firebug to ensure that your linked JS files are all being found and loaded. Your code in JSFiddle works as expected with an additional hook to check the validate is getting called;

```
showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
                alert("Here!");
              }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dABZr/1/

Answer (score 0):

some time there is two time

```
$(document).ready(function(){
////bla bla bla
}
```

in page, may be one is in header, and other is in footer, so this error comes, check your file again...